# Google Maps Api Can't Display Marker with Json (v3)

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I created google maps with Json and used database postgresql

this is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map;

  var national = [{"lng":"-6.173319","city":"JAKARTA","lat":"106.818672"}];

  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-0.789275,113.921327),
      zoom: 5,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

  $.getJSON('json_city.json', function(data) { 
    $.each( data.national, function(index, item) {
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(item.lat, item.lng);
      alert(myLatlng);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: "text "+item.city
      });
    });
  });

  // Initialize the map
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Lat and long used character type (Text). My maps can show, but my marker can't show.

Comment: You have a typo in you `national` variable; `lat` and `lng` are backwards (should be `"lat": "-6.173319", "lng": "106.818672"`). ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/f3rwcdyd/))

Comment: Thank your correction @geocodezip

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps needs coordinates for the LatLng constructor to be Numbers, not strings.  Try:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(item.lat), parseFloat(item.lng));
```

Comment: i tried, but didn't work.
i had checked in console.log("item.lat"); and console.log("item.lng"); and my google chrome can't show log. @duncan

Comment: What does `data.national` look like?  You've hardcoded `var national` in the top of your JS, but it's not used.